# Limiting Docker resources in WSL2. But not my Ubuntu WSL2 development environment

Tags: docker, wsl-2, hyper-v

So I am having the following issue:

I want to limit the resources Docker is able to use within WSL2.
The answers that I have currently found say that I can limit it with the WSL2 config file.

However, when I edit the file and limit the WSL2 RAM usage I encounter the issue that my WSL2 Ubuntu instance lacks in RAM to be able to build the Front-End project.

I have found a solution to limit Docker to run it on Hyper-V.
Now the issue is that I can't start the Docker images of Back-End from WSL2 and that I should enable WSL2 again for Docker.

Running Back-End outside WSL2 is a lot of work (since some tools are not Windows-supported).

---

So I hoped to find a configuration to have specific settings for my WSL2 Ubuntu instance and have the rest limited via the global WSL2 config.

Or be able to start Hyper-V Docker images from WSL2

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints).

Docker containers don’t have any default limitations for the host’s resources usage.

But, you can limit the resource of a specific contaienr with the --memory/-m `--cpus/-c` flags, such as:

```
docker run --cpus=1 --memory=256m <image-name>
```